# Url redirect to Playstore

Tags: android, nfc

I want to write url onto the tag, but once I write the url onto the tag it took me the android store.

I want to write url as www.example.com but it took me on `android.market.com/details?id=www.example.com` something like that.

My code:

```
package se.anyro.nfc_reader;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import se.anyro.nfc_reader.record.ParsedNdefRecord;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * An {@link Activity} which handles a broadcast of a new tag that the device just discovered.
 */
public class TagViewer extends Activity {

    private static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    private LinearLayout mTagContent;
    private String url = "www.google.com/";
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private NdefMessage mNdefPushMessage;
    private static final String EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME = "package_name";
    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tag_viewer);
        mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
        resolveIntent(getIntent());

        mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).create();

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.no_nfc);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        mNdefPushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord(
                "Message from NFC Reader :-)", Locale.ENGLISH, true) });
    }

    private void showMessage(int title, int message) {
        mDialog.setTitle(title);
        mDialog.setMessage(getText(message));
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private NdefRecord newTextRecord(String text, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
        byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

        Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
        byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes(utfEncoding);

        int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
        char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);

        byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
        data[0] = (byte) status;
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showWirelessSettingsDialog();
            }
            mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
            mAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this, mNdefPushMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            mAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
        }
    }

    private void showWirelessSettingsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.nfc_disabled);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
        return;
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs;
        //    Log.e("", "dump data is  : "+dumpTagData(rawMsgs).getBytes());
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            } else {
                // Unknown tag type
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
                Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                byte[] payload = dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                Log.e("", "dump data is  : "+dumpTagData(tag).getBytes());
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record });
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] { msg };
            }

          String packageName = url;
        //  String packageName = url+""+sb;

          Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
          Log.e("", "printed : "+packageName);
          writeApplicationRecordOnTag(packageName, tag);
          Log.e("", packageName);
            // Setup the views
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }

    private String dumpTagData(Parcelable p) {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        Tag tag = (Tag) p;
        byte[] id = tag.getId();
        sb.append("Tag ID (hex): ").append(getHex(id)).append("\n");
        sb.append("Tag ID (dec): ").append(getDec(id)).append("\n");
        sb.append("ID (reversed): ").append(getReversed(id)).append("\n");

        String prefix = "android.nfc.tech.";
        sb.append("Technologies: ");
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            sb.append(tech.substring(prefix.length()));
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            if (tech.equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareClassic mifareTag = MifareClassic.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareTag.getType()) {
                case MifareClassic.TYPE_CLASSIC:
                    type = "Classic";
                    break;
                case MifareClassic.TYPE_PLUS:
                    type = "Plus";
                    break;
                case MifareClassic.TYPE_PRO:
                    type = "Pro";
                    break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Classic type: ");
                sb.append(type);
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare size: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getSize() + " bytes");
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare sectors: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getSectorCount());
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare blocks: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getBlockCount());
            }

            if (tech.equals(MifareUltralight.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareUltralight mifareUlTag = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareUlTag.getType()) {
                case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
                    type = "Ultralight";
                    break;
                case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C:
                    type = "Ultralight C";
                    break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Ultralight type: ");
                sb.append(type);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
            if (b < 0x10)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private long getDec(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private long getReversed(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;
    }

    void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LinearLayout content = mTagContent;

        // Parse the first message in the list
        // Build views for all of the sub records
        Date now = new Date();
        List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
        final int size = records.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TextView timeView = new TextView(this);
            timeView.setText(TIME_FORMAT.format(now));
            content.addView(timeView, 0);
            ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);
            content.addView(record.getView(this, inflater, content, i), 1 + i);
            content.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_divider, content, false), 2 + i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        resolveIntent(intent);

        // write tag valkues 
//        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           // String packageName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME);
//           String packageName = "amit";
//            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
//            Log.e("", "printed : "+packageName);
//            writeApplicationRecordOnTag(packageName, tag);
//            Log.e("", packageName);
//       }
    }


    private void writeApplicationRecordOnTag(String packageName, Tag tag) {
        NdefMessage msg = NfcUtils.getApplicationRecord(packageName);
        writeNdefMessageToTag(msg, tag);
        unFreezeUi();
    }

    private void writeNdefMessageToTag(NdefMessage message, Tag tag) {
        try {
            NfcUtils.writeTag(message, tag);
            printWritingResult(true, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            printWritingResult(false, e);
        }
    }


    private void printWritingResult(boolean result, Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getErrorMessage(result, exception), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    private String getErrorMessage(boolean result, Exception exception) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (result)
            sb.append("getString(R.string.error_success)");
        else
            sb.append("getString(R.string.error_fail)");

        if (exception != null) {
            sb.append(exception.getMessage());
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }


    private void freezeUi() {
//        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void unFreezeUi() {
//        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me, that you have written an *Android Application Record* (AAR) into the RFID tag. If you do so, and your Android device reads an AAR, maybe together with other NDEF records, it tries to open the specific application (the AAR is pointing to) on your device. If the device is not available it will guide you to the market place.

Try to add **only** an NDEF record with a simple URL (not the AAR).